# String functions in VBA ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to write a string formula `Left(a1,2)` in VBA within a range.
Must use variables for "a1" to "a30" and "k1" to "k30"

| Text in "a1" | result in "k1" |
| --- | --- |
| 03_15 | 03 |
| .. | .. |
| .. | .. |
| 12_21 | 12 |

Down to 30+ lines down.
I've tried this:

```vb
Cells(i, 8).Formula = "=left(A" & i &, 2")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Range("K1:K30").formula = "=Left(A1,2)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're just missing a double quote after the last ampersand:

```
Cells(i, 8).Formula = "=left(A" & i & ", 2")
```

When concatenating you should end up with an even number of quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

### Write Formulas to Dynamic Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeFormulaToRange()
    ' Source First Cell Address
    Const srcFirstCell As String = "A1"
    ' Destination Column ID (Number or String)
    Const dstColID As Variant = "K" ' or 11
    ' Declare Variables.
    Dim srcRng As Range ' Source Range
    Dim srcLastRow As Long ' Source Last Row
    Dim ColOffset As Long ' Column Offset
    ' Define First Cell Range.
    With Range(srcFirstCell)
        ' Source Column is the column of the First Cell Range.
        ' Source Last Row is the row of the Last Non-Empty Cell Range
        ' in Source Column.
        ' Calculate Source Last Row.
        srcLastRow = .Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row
        ' Source Range is the range from the First Cell Range
        ' to the Last Non-Empty Cell Range.
        ' Define Source Range.
        Set srcRng = .Resize(srcLastRow - .Row + 1)
        ' Column Offset is the difference between the Destination
        ' and the Source Column Numbers.
        ' Calculate Column Offset.
        ColOffset = .Worksheet.Columns(dstColID).Column - .Column
    End With
    ' Destination Range is of the same size as the Source Range.
    ' Write the formulas to the Destination Range.
    srcRng.Offset(, ColOffset).Value = "=Left(" & srcFirstCell & ",2)"
    ' or:
    'rng.Offset(, ColOffset).Formula = "=Left(" & srcFirstCell & ",2)"
End Sub
```